How to get details of selected item in Droplink used as a rendering parameter in next js in Sitecore XM Colud
I have a Droplink field in rendering parameter and I want name of selected item in Droplink in nextjs.
I get guid id of the selected item of Droplink in params in nextjs but not other details of the selected item.


You can set the following configuration to true to get the detailed information on rendering parameters.
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="LayoutService.DetailedRenderingParams" value="false">
        <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
    </setting>
   </settings>
 </sitecore>

This will return all the fields of the droplink item rather the droplink item id and will work on XMCloud Environment.
By default this setting is set to false in the XMCloud environment.

Hope this helps!!

Where to find these config files on XM Cloud.

You can add above as a config patch and there is a setting, which is set to false by default on the XM Cloud..

This fix did not worked.

Can you check the config patch applied correctly on XMCloud environment through showconfig.aspx page.

Is this setting only available in XM Cloud or should this work in XM (10.3) as well?
